# Programming ATMega48 with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, atmega

I'm trying to build a circuit that uses an ATMega48 PDIP-style chip and an ATTiny26. I'm stuck on loading code onto the ATMega48 using an Arduino Uno.

I've been following [these](http://pdp11.byethost12.com/AVR/ArduinoAsProgrammer.htm) instructions. I got all the way to step 4 when I got this error:

```
>avrdude -P COM3 -b 19200 -c avrisp -p m48 -n

[...]

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e920a
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA48 is 1E 92 05
         Double-check chip, or use -F to override this check.

[...]
```

I did the easy thing and added the -F option, and everything seemed to work out. Then I added the hexfile (following the format specified in the guide) and got this:

```
>avrdude -P COM3 -b 19200 -c avrisp -p m328p -u -U flash:
w:"[...]\build2681525234531849420.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex":i -F

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.07s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e920a
avrdude: Expected signature for ATMEGA328P is 1E 95 0F
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed

         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "[...]\build2681525234531849420.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (1084 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 1.34s

avrdude: 1084 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against [...]\build2681525234531849420.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file [...]\build2681525234531849420.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex:
avrdude: input file [...]\build2681525234531849420.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex contains 1084 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.98s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002
         0x61 != 0x01
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

How do I go about fixing this?

For the record, I'm using the "minimal" configuration specified [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard):

Arduino -> Mega48

10 -> 1

11 -> 17

12 -> 18

13 -> 19

Comment: Got it to work! Just had to change -m328p to -m48.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an ATmega48p, judging from the signature, so use `-p m48p` to get rid of the signature error.

I don’t know whether that alone will fix things, but the ATmega328 has a different flash page size and doubtlessly other differences from the mega48, so ignoring the signature was unlikely to work (I think `-F` for anything but diagnostic purposes is a bad move).